# Codeigniter blog application bug: form is loaded without validation errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am working on a **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4. I have an "Edit post" form with *validation*.

If validation fails (because the *Title* field has been emptied, for example), the form should reload *with validation errors*.

My `update()` (lives in the Posts controller) method is wrong: it uses a redirect, so the form is reloaded **without** validation errors, to its initial state.

```
public function edit($id) {
    // Only logged in users can edit posts
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->sidebar_posts($limit=5, $offset=0);
    $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $data['post']->author_id) {
        $data['tagline'] = 'Edit the post "' . $data['post']->title . '"';
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('edit-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        /* If the current user is not the author
        of the post do not alow edit */
        redirect('/' . $id);
    }
}

public function update() {
    // Form data validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    // Update slug (from title)
    if (!empty($this->input->post('title'))) {
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }
    } else {
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
    }

// Upload image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('/' . $slug);
    } else {
        redirect('/posts/edit/' . $slug);
    }
}
```

I am almost certain the problem is this line: `redirect('/posts/edit/' . $slug);` but I have not been able to find a viable alternative.

Using `$this->edit($id)` instead of `redirect('/posts/edit/' . $slug);` does not work either. I wish it would, because I want to keep the code DRY.

What shall I change?

---

**Edit.** I did this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('/' . $slug);
} else {
        $this->form_validation->run();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
        var_dump($this->session->flashdata('errors'));
        //redirect('/posts/edit/' . $slug);
}
```

The `var_dump($this->session->flashdata('errors'));` returns all the validation errors.

I wish to add the class `has-error` to the form-group and append <`p class="error-message">The Title field is required.</p>`.

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control error" placeholder="Title" data-rule-required="true" value="Learn to code with us" aria-invalid="true">
  <p class="error-message">The Title field is required.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: load the view in the function instead of redirect, or you can put the errors in session to display after redirect

Comment: And I have just noticed you are not checking if the user has permission to edit the post in your update method just in your edit method (you should never assume a user won't try to post directly to a different post id) so it's a good idea to add the same check in both methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the desired result using `set_flashdata()` as suggested by @Alex

In the controller I have:

```
public function update() {
    // Form data validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    // Update slug (from title)
    if (!empty($this->input->post('title'))) {
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }
    } else {
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
    }

// Upload image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('/' . $slug);
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->run();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
        redirect('/posts/edit/' . $slug);
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('errors')) {
         $errors = $this->session->flashdata('errors');
         echo '<div class="error-group alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">' . "\n";
         echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' . "\n";
         echo $errors;
         echo '<p class="error-message">We have restored the post.</p>';
         echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 options:

1. Use flash data in update method on failure (you are already using it on success). Simply assign the errors to a flash data variable and get it after you redirect back to edit.
2. Combine edit and update methods (most common for non-ajax usage).
3. Use ajax and return json encoded strings for errors or success messages.

Option 2:

This option also solves the potential authentication issue pointed out in the comments.

Please read the comments embedded in the code.

```
public function edit($id) {
        // Only logged in users can edit posts
        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
            redirect('login');
        }

        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);

        if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $data['post']->author_id) {
            show_error('Access denied'); // function exits
        }

        if ($_POST) {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required', array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required', array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required', array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

            //$id = $this->input->post('id'); not required anymore

            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload()) {
                // always use the name from the upload lib
                // sometimes it changes it in case of duplicates (read docs for more)
                $post_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');

                // doesn't make sense with title validation rule, this will always be true to get
                // passed validation
                if (!empty($this->input->post('title'))) {
                    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
                    $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
                    if ($slugcount > 0) {
                        $slug = $slug . "-" . $slugcount;
                    }
                } else {
                    $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
                }

                $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
                redirect('/' . $slug);
            } else {
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors() . $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
        }

        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->sidebar_posts($limit = 5, $offset = 0);
        $data['tagline'] = 'Edit the post "' . $data['post']->title . '"';
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('edit-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }
```

Comment: I do not want a flash message, I just want the invalid form to be returned. I could do this validation on the front-end and I *will*, but I need back-end validation in (the unlikely) case users would disable JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this scenario is merge both methods into a single method relying on the validation to know if I am saving the entry or not.

your code would look something like this:

```
public function edit($id) {
    // Only logged in users can edit posts
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }
    $Post = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);
    // user does not own the post, redirect
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') !== $Post->author_id) {
        redirect('/' . $id);
    }

    // Form data validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    // if validation fails, or the form isn't submitted
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === false ) {
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->sidebar_posts($limit=5, $offset=0);
        $data['post'] = $Post;

        $data['tagline'] = 'Edit the post "' . $data['post']->title . '"';
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('edit-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }else{
        // Update slug (from title)
        if (! empty($this->input->post('title'))) {
            $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
            $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
            if ($slugcount > 0) {
                $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
            }
        } else {
            $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
        }
        // Upload image
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }       
        $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('/' . $slug);
    }
}
```

and you don't have to implement the update separately, you just post to /edit/$id instead of /update/$id ... this is a rough example, your slug checking (which I haven't touched upon) is not the correct way to do it, if it passes the validation the title is already filled since it's set to required so I guess you meant `if (! empty(slug) )`, but again in your else you are setting the slug directly from user input, so I would add it to the validation and make sure it's unique in the database except for the $id that's being edited currently.

Again, this is the result of copy & paste from your original code i might have missed something so give it a good read to make sure nothing is missing and include the validation errors in the data you are passing to the view.

Comment: A want to be able to use simething like `$this->edit($id)` instead of `redirect('/posts/edit/' . $slug);` to keep my code as DRY as possible.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly an option ... have you tried that?

Comment: I did, but for some reason it does not work. I can paste the entire app here. So, here  it is on **[Github](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog)**. Hava a look.

Comment: what errors do you get? I think it should work just fine you have the $id & it's available in the same class.

Comment: I am redirected to `siteurl.com/post_id` instead of `siteurl.com/posts/edit/post_slug`. And I see a "Sorry, we could not find the content you ware looking for" message.

Comment: its is kind of obvious why your way doesn't work when you think about it. `$this->edit` only options are to redirect, fv is failing hence why you are going to `redirect('/' . $slug);`. further, redirect = runtime data gone e.g. `validation_errors` empty. not to mention, the url changes which is sloppy.